# MVC3 (Razor) radio buttons checks

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, radio-button

In first,I have to create some radio buttons in a mvc3 partial view.

When I'm on the screen I need to select only one radio button and retrieved a specific value.

How can I do this (with JS or C# for example) ?

```
            <div id="UserDeleteInfosField">
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("HasUserLeave", new { id = "rb1" })
                    @UserAccountResources.UserLeave
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserLeave)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("HasUserTransfer", new { id = "rb2" })
                    @UserAccountResources.UserTransfer
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserTransfer)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("HasUserDetachment", new { id = "rb3" })
                    @UserAccountResources.UserDetachment
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserDetachment)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("HasUserRetirement", new { id = "rb4" })
                    @UserAccountResources.UserRetirement
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserRetirement)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("HasUserStatus", new { id = "rb5" })
                    @UserAccountResources.UserStatus
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserStatus)   
                </p>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance !

Ars_n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at example to understand how radio buttons are grouped: [example](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

You need same `name` attribute, like here:

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water" /> Water<br />
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer" /> Beer<br />
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine" checked /> Wine<br />
```

Your example:

```
@Html.RadioButton("SameGroup", "rb1")
@Html.RadioButton("SameGroup", "rb2")
@Html.RadioButton("SameGroup", "rb3")
@Html.RadioButton("SameGroup", "rb4")
@Html.RadioButton("SameGroup", "rb5")
```

Only checked value you will receive in controller action on post.

Comment: You might also want to generate [labels with unique ids](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611175/Radio-Buttons-for-List-Items-in-MVC-Problem-with) so that clicking `Water`, etc. actually selects the radio button.

Answer (score 8):

So you need a group of radiobuttons? I use a custom helper for that.

Code for the helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(
       this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
       Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (listOfValues != null)
        {
            // Create a radio button for each item in the list 
            foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
            {
                // Generate an id to be given to the radio button field 
                var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);

                // Create and populate a radio button using the existing html helpers 
                var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));

                var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();

                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = id, @checked = "checked", }).ToHtmlString();
                }


                // Create the html string that will be returned to the client 
                // e.g. <input data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an option" id="TestRadio_1" name="TestRadio" type="radio" value="1" /><label for="TestRadio_1">Line1</label> 
                sb.AppendFormat("<div class=\"RadioButton\">{0}{1}</div>", radio, label);
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

now in your view you can just use:

```
@Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(model => model.yourproperty, Model.listUsedToPopulate)
```

Now you'll only be able to check one of the radiobuttons at the time. The checked value is stored in model.yourproperty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Finally I opted for another solution (group radio buttons).

Comment: If you find yourself inside a collection, then the label for is going to "intelligently" insert IDForModel before your id. You going to need to use this variable for your radio buttons id: var modelID = string.Format("{0}_{1}", htmlHelper.IdForModel(), id);

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to post this to an controller method, so maybe this is what you are trying to do:

Let's say the controller method takes a parameter called `myParameter`, then you would need to set the name of the radio buttons to the same to group them, then set the value to whatever you need:

```
<div id="UserDeleteInfosField">
    <p>
        @Html.RadioButton("myParameter", UserAccountResources.UserLeave)
        @UserAccountResources.UserLeave
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserLeave)   
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        @Html.RadioButton("myParameter", UserAccountResources.UserTransfer)
        @UserAccountResources.UserTransfer
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserTransfer)   
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        @Html.RadioButton("myParameter", UserAccountResources.UserDetachment)
        @UserAccountResources.UserDetachment
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserDetachment)   
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        @Html.RadioButton("myParameter", UserAccountResources.UserRetirement)
        @UserAccountResources.UserRetirement
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserRetirement)   
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        @Html.RadioButton("myParameter", UserAccountResources.UserStatus)
        @UserAccountResources.UserStatus
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserStatus)   
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I finally create one group for each radio buttons. 
And I call the property in rb object parameter.

```
            <div id="UserDeleteInfosField">
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("RbDeleteGroup", Model.UserLeave)
                    @UserAccountResources.UserLeave
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserLeave)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("RbDeleteGroup", Model.UserTransfer)
                    @UserAccountResources.UserTransfer
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserTransfer)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("RbDeleteGroup", Model.UserDetachment)
                    @UserAccountResources.UserDetachment
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserDetachment)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("RbDeleteGroup", Model.UserRetirement)
                    @UserAccountResources.UserRetirement
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserRetirement)   
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @Html.RadioButton("RbDeleteGroup", Model.UserStatus)
                    @UserAccountResources.UserStatus
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserStatus)   
                </p>
            </div>
```

So in this case I can only check one radio button at the same time and retrieved the property value from the respective ViewModel.

```
    [Display(Name = "UserAccountDeleteInfos", ResourceType = typeof(UserAccountResources))]
    public string UserLeave
    {
        get { return UserAccountResources.UserLeave; }
    }
```